# Terminal does not call 'then', reports a syntax error and command not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, centos

I have CentOS 7. I am running a very simple script from BASH. I executed the chmod command and then ran the script file from a terminal. I got an error saying "if command not found" and that it is a syntax error. Can you please help me resolving this?

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Enter a number:"
read number
if["$num" -eq 10]
then
echo "the number is 10"
elif["$num" -lt 10]
then
echo "that number is less then 10"
elif["$num" -gt 10]
then
echo "this is greater than 10"
else
echo "the number is between 10 and 20"
fi
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a number:
100
./arya.sh: line 6: if[ -eq 10]: command not found
./arya.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./arya.sh: line 7: `then'
```

Comment: Spaces MATTER.  Try `if [condition] ....`

Comment: Or, (much much) better yet, `if  [ ` *`condition `* `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a least one space between `[` / `]` and anything next to them:

```
if [ "$num" -eq 10 ]
```

`[` is actually a bash command, an alias for the `test` command that evaluates your expressions, and the closing `]` has to stand on its own so it won't be evaluated as part of the expression.

Comment: As well, the OP is reading `number` but testing `$num`

Comment: @steeldriver Right, didn't even notice that. (I wrote this answer before eyoung100 fixed the code formatting in the question, so I only skimmed the code.)